# create total accordif if column is filled

Tags: sql

I want to count the number of total people who will attend to an event and this number is calculated by the person who invites and how many people will be invited.
So I have this info,

```
 refInqCredLink RegisterDate    Name    Phone   Email   Horario Insc1   Insc2   Insc3
496 2019-08-29 15:38:13.183 Abilio  91 abilio@hotmail.com   3   albano  jorge   
497 2019-08-30 14:12:46.873 Duarte  25 duarte@sapo.pt   3   antonio     
499 2019-08-30 14:48:29.067 AGOSTINHO 92 agostinho@gmail.com    1   Jorge Antonio   Manuel Fernando
```

In this case "John" will attend the event and will invite "albano" and "jorge". So the total number of people in this line is 3.

I need to check if Insc1, Insc2 and Insc3 column have value and if so (<>'') count as 1 person. I need to create a view based in this table with this sum.

If I try this code,

```
Select 
SUM(case when not Name is null  then 1 else 0 end
+ 
case when not Insc1 is null then 1 else 0 end
+ 
case when not Insc2 is null then 1 else 0 end
+ 
case when not Insc3 is null then 1 else 0 end) 
from LACTINFO_InquiryCredential_Link_Seminario
```

this returns 12 instead of 8.

I have 3 Names + 5 Invitees = 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
Select 
SUM(case when Insc1 is null or Insc1 = ''  then 0 else 1 end
+ 
case when Insc2 is null  or Insc2 = ''  then 0 else 1 end
+ 
case when Insc3 is null  or Insc3 = ''  then 0 else 1 end) 
+
count(*)
from tab
```

Comment: This count's more elements than I have.. I've updated my answer with 3 rows and the total should be 8 instead of 12.

Comment: @CátiaMatos check it https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6018c32fee03159f2becbf781528a930

Comment: I've take a printscreen

Comment: @CátiaMatos i edited the awnser. The problem was that you had the string empty as value on Insc1, Insc2, Insc3. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=10d952eaeeb3ff250a7b0ee0d4f5cb27

Answer (score 1):

To get the total, you can use `count()`:

```
select count(*) +                                   -- everyone is counted once
       count(insc1) + count(insc2) + count(insc3)   -- additional invitees
from t;
```

First, note that this is a poor data model.  You should have a separate table with one row per person invited.

Second, the same person could be invited multiple times.  This formulation does not take that into account.  Using just first names makes it hard to deduplicate the data.